# Trying to find a way Prevent a Type Mismatch error from Occring in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

```
Sub Calculate_NNA_NMEXRegionUnits_Pacific()
Dim a, rand, AsInteger As Integer
For a = 8 To 42 
 Cells(26, a) = Round(Cells(27, a) * Cells(27, 7) * (Cells(22, 2) - Cells(22, 3) - Cells(20, 7)), 0)
Next a
```

I'm making a program that performs a set of calculation on a range (26,a). The formula data type is variant/integer, while the data type on the range is variant/object/range. I am curious if I can ensure both sides of this equation are the same data type, I was looking at ways to change the formula, I've also worked with type conversion formulas. I have not been successful. I am asking for assistance to prevent a  Type mismatch from occurring on row 4 so my code can proceed.

```
rerand1:
    rand = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(9, 27) 'Excludes base trim in random addition because of restrictions
    If Cells(27, rand) = 0 Then
        GoTo rerand1 'Wont change a 0 value, because it might be intentionally zero.
    Else
        If Cells(26, 7) < Cells(22, 2) - (Cells(22, 3) + Cells(20, 7)) Then Cells(26, rand) = Cells(26, rand) + 1 'If there is less than the total, add.
        If Cells(26, 7) > Cells(22, 2) - (Cells(22, 3) + Cells(20, 7)) Then Cells(26, rand) = Cells(26, rand) - 1 'If there is more than the total, subtract.
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

This is the next step of my code if it is needed to solve the problem

Comment: Try declaring rand as a long, then `rand=clng(Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(9, 27) )`  Not sure what `Dim a, rand, AsInteger As Integer` is meant to do, you have a variable called AsInteger, which is the only one declared As Integer.

Answer (score 1):

`Type mismatch` can occur not only because you have different value types. You can also get that error if there is a formula error in that cell. For example if you type `=0/0` in cell `A1` and then in immediate window if you execute `?Val([A1].value)`, you will get the `Type Mismatch` error.

Here is one way to achieve what you want. Try and store the value in a temp variable and then use that for the comparision.

```
Dim tmpVal As Integer

rand = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(9, 27)

On Error Resume Next
tmpVal = Cells(27, rand)
On Error GoTo 0

If tmpVal = 0 Then

Else

End If
```

Comment: The error occurs at row 4. If you just delete the 2nd section of code I added the type mismatch error will still occur. The first set of code is what is causing the TYPE mismatch error. the range(26,A) actually does change it's values for it's cells, the issue is It does not allow me to proceed further with my code once the values change in that range.

Comment: You mean you are getting the error at `Cells(26, a) = Round(Cells(27, a)...` ?

Comment: Yes, I am unsure why it would be changing the values for the range and then stopping the computation saying there is a type mismatch. I'm still a novice with VBA but shouldn't the values not change if there is a TYPE mismatch for that section of the code.

Comment: Technically `Error` *is* a data type though =)

Comment: @CanadianBeaver the answer to that is in the worksheet data: when code halts, hit Ctrl+G and type `?TypeNameCells(27,a).Value)` - and do that for all cells involved in the computation; one of them must be `Error`. You need to either fix your worksheet to avoid worksheet errors (e.g. `#VALUE!` or `#N/A`), or fix your code to avoid attempting to do math against a data type that can't do math (`Error`, or a non-numeric `String`).

Comment: @CanadianBeaver: A good practice is to use `IfError()` with formulas to avoid any errors. This way your code will not crash.

Comment: Thanks, I've found the error, there was a date data type for some of the cells in the range. I've changed those data types and the code works fine now. Also I will utilize IFERROR more frequently.